# What's the best way to store different dimension items in a grid

Tags: object, 2d

I'm creating a puzzle like game with blocks in a grid. These blocks are all 1xY or Xx1 in size. If I have a block class like this:

```
Block{
  Orientation (vertical / horizontal)
  Length (integer)
}
```

What might be the best way to store data about its coordinates on a grid? Because almost all blocks will take up more than one space along the x*y axis. Should I store the coordinate data inside the block and (When displaying the grid with the blocks) generate a board based on that, or should I keep the coordinate data inside the 2d array itself. Or some mixture of both?

The blocks will eventually be able to move along its orientation while considering collision with other blocks so that maybe an important factor in this implementation